# Where does Lynx broswer download files?

Tags: ubuntu, lynx

I am using Lynx command line browser on Ubuntu. I have a `Generate Report` button on my web page which when clicked, would download an Excel report from my Rails application.

I am not able to find where the downloaded files go.

Please help! Where do the downloaded files go in Lynx browser?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else new to Lynx that finds this, make sure you use the [download command](https://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx_help/Lynx_users_guide.html#RemoteSource)  (focus on the link to the file, then hit `d`), and Lynx will ask you for a path/filename (if you don't specify the full path, it will save to the current working directory).

If you just try to browse the link instead, Lynx will download it to a temporary location then try to preview it (for me, browsing an `.xlsx` file link in Lynx will download it to `/tmp` then launch LibreOffice).

Comment: How do you do this from the ***command line***?

Answer (score 1):

Usually Lynx will save downloaded files in the same directory where you started Lynx.

For example, if you are at your home directory `/path/to/myhomedir` and start lynx there, then the downloaded file should be at `/path/to/myhomedir/[downloaded-file]`